# Ejecutar código sql haciendo un fetch array

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Tengo una buscador que encontré en google y me gustaría que cuando lo utilice busque en la base de datos 'barcode' y si encuentra a la persona ejecute el código que esta bajo $statement (ese código bajo $statement yo lo añadí), no me interesa un echo de la información por eso eliminé esa parte y coloque un refresh, solo me interesaría que ejecute los cambios en el query del sql una vez encuentre a la persona que se esta buscando, no tiene que ser el código como esta a continuación, en realidad no se como hacerlo y vengo por ayuda.

```
<?php
    include 'includes/conn.php';
    include 'includes/scripts.php'; 


    if (isset($_POST['no'])) {
        $sca=trim($_POST['no'],""); 
        $credentials="";
        $new2 ="SELECT * FROM `barcode`";
        $mysqli = new $conn;
        $statement= $mysqli->prepare("Insert IGNORE into voters
                                    Select * from barcode where id = id;
                                    DELETE from barcode where id IN(SELECT id from voters)");
        $res2=mysqli_query($conn, $new2);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){
           if($row['credentials'] == $sca){
              $statement->execute();
              header("refresh: .5");
           }       
        }
    }
    $statement->close();
    mysqli_close($conn);
 
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu lógica. ¿Por qué de entrada no escribes la consulta así y punto: `SELECT * FROM `barcode WHERE credentials = ?` y haces un `bind_param` del valor de `$sca`?

Comment: Es un código que encontré de una barra de search, que busca en una base de datos y si encuentra a la persona hace un echo de la información, y me gustaría añadirle el INSERT IGNORE sin que me devuelva un echo por eso borre esa parte y no esta en el código. No necesariamente necesito ese código exactamente como esta escrito en el post, pero no se como sería.

Comment: Nosotros nos basamos en el código y en lo que quieras hacer, para responder a las preguntas. Entonces explica con claridad lo que quieres y luego nos dices el código que has intentado y te ayudaremos a corregirlo/mejorarlo, pero con un código donde pones cosas que no son necesarias, es complicado siquiera entender el problema.